# unable to execute /usr/bin/qmicli: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, mobile-broadband-api

I am using linux kernel 3.6.9 with Sierra wireless MC7354. This module plugged with Verizon wireless activated sim card with ARM9 processor based embedded board. By enabling kernel qcserial driver and qmi_wwan drivers, we are able to get ifconfig –a command output as follows:

```
wwan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 1A:11:193:11:11
BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

To establish broadband connection, thought of speak with modem by using libqmi protocol approach. Downloaded libqmi-1.12.6 in my development Ubuntu machine and configured with ARM compiler.

After making, moved 
qmi-network  qmicli  qmi-proxy programs to my actual embedded board 
usr/bin folder and

libqmi-glib.so, libqmi-glib.so.1 and libqmi-glib.so.1.3.0 to usr/lib folders.

(Can’t install actual target board with limited memory card limitations).

When I try to run

```
./qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 status
```

Getting following error:

```
Loading profile...
APN: VZW
Getting status with 'qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wds-get-packet-service-status '...
./qmi-network: line 257: qmicli: not found
error: couldn't get packet service status
```

Some reason I couldn’t able to run qmicli program in my target board.
Can anyone help me on this….

Looks like I am missing copying some dependencies from my linux development machine to target ARM platform.

Thanks,

Comment: Check that `usr/bin` is in your `$PATH` and that `qmicli` is executable. Does it let you execute `qmicli` from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your suggestion Marco.

> Some reason I couldn’t able to run qmicli program in my target board.
>   Can anyone help me on this….

Actual cause of this problem is with wrong cross compile options selected while configuring and building libqmi libraries.

After rebuilding, able to execute qmicli commands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

qmi-network relies on qmicli being in the $PATH, I guess that's your issue.

BUT, the location of the qmi-proxy binary is chosen during compilation of libqmi; it is set to the "`--libexec=`" defined or to the default one (`$prefix/libexec`) if none specified.

A usual compilation would use `--prefix=/usr` during configure, and this will end up installing:

```
/usr/bin/qmicli
/usr/bin/qmi-network
/usr/lib/libqmi.*
/usr/libexec/qmi-proxy
```

I'd suggest you first try to play with qmicli directly, and only once everything works, play with qmi-network (which is just a wrapper script on top of qmicli).